# recommendation on design/architecture for centralized DB application in .net

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am a junior .NET programmer.
I have to develop an applicaion that handles sales, customers and providers (among another very large number of things) on a local environment for a small number of users (around 8).
The whole thing should be created for local use with a centralized database.
My architecture would be something like this from top to bottom:

1.UI on windows forms.

2.Controller for handling user requests

3.Bussines objects that are Entity Framework generated objects

4.SQL Database.

Obviously I already know that is not the best approach for architecture, yet I want to keep it as simple as possible.
I've done a lot of research but the number of questions seems to widen so I was looking for some guidance for this particular problem so I can focus in researching after having a recommended architecture I feel comfortable with. Sorry about uberasking this question I'm just overwhelmed with the options.

Tnx for helping a newb.

Comment: MSDN has a an entity framework overview with a sample project.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx  SO is for specific programming questions.

Comment: Thank you, I used that very article for deciding on EF4 over other techologies, yet it doesnt approaches the layered question.

Comment: Then for the middle layer look to WCF Windows Communication Foundation.  The middle tier is hosted as a service (typically in IIS) and WCF is used to communicate from the client to the service.  Consider WPF over Forms for your client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described seems like a good approach coming form a junior developer level.

There are many factors that affect what architecture is appropriate for a project. Time, schedule, money, simplicity or complexity, maintainability and future development expansion versus a one-and-done application. Will likely future versions require a massive rewrite anyway due to the data model or integration with some unknown system?

No application is ever perfect after the first iteration. Any good developer will find a myriad of ways to improve a project after it is finished as their technical skills and knowledge grow.

That being said, the Database and Entity Framework side of things is perfectly fine. EF will get you focusing on features quickly instead of infrastructure. You may have already weighed EF against other object model suites, or a traditional stored procedure based approach.

The UI is probably dictated by the client or a business need. The only other big decision here would maybe be an intranet web application so you don't have to worry about installing software on users' machines.

The controller / class library / business layer makes sense so you don't have to be writing queries against EF directly in your winforms code. This allows you to more easily rip out the UI and replace it with something else down the line.

Nothing you've outlined throws up any red flags without knowing the exact situation. Move forward with that approach, and see how it goes. When you're done, think about what aspects of the architecture were challenging to deal with, were redundant, or otherwise troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's good to know I'm in the right track! Another question though: if I switch to a Web application instead of using Windows forms, what additional layers would I be needing, I understand I'll have to have a Service Layer to provide to the website, and then I don't know if I should be using the same objects from the Business layer to go back and forth to the server from the UI.

Comment: Also, where should I place validation? Always confusing to me where is the best place to add validation rules.

Comment: Re: if web app: you wouldn't necessarily need any extra layers. A standard asp.net website/webapp's codebehind pages should be able to directly call methods on your controller/business layer. A separate service to serve the data would be useful if you had multiple different applications that needed to access the same data/functions. If you just have one app, there's no need for a service (yet).

Comment: Thinking too much about validation can make it tricky. The easiest place to enforce validation is through the UI. That works for required fields, and other simple validations. More complex logic needs a call to some business object/method or comparing data in the repository. In the end, you'll need to give feedback to the user, which gets you again to the UI. I think all developers go through a phase at some point of trying to wrap up all validation in some central module. I'd recommend not thinking too hard about this one. It should flow naturally once you start coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you said the Entity Framework objects are generated, you may want to have one or more Model levels between the Controller and the Entity objects. It is quite often that a specific View has data coming from more than one Entity. If you do not have another level of Models that the Controllers can access, what generally happens is that the Business Logic migrates to the Controllers.

In other words, the Controller would create the Model, and the Model would know how to interact with the Entities.

Note that I am assuming you are using an MVC pattern since your reference of Controllers in #2.

Comment: I though MVC was a framework created for UI. I don't see the difference here between the entities and the Model, for me they were the same in my design.

Comment: My controllers where actually classes that take use cases and divide into different steps to achieve the complete operation

Comment: Only the View in MVC is for the UI. The Controllers handle the request, and the Models contain data and perform business logic. I am using the term Model very loosely, entities are Models. 

So generally in MVC, the Controller doesn't act upon the entities. It simply takes the HTTP request and transforms it as parameters to the Models which then acts upon the data. 

It appears you are using more of a service base approach, so in generally just think of the Models as the service layer.